# Redirecting to rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a user visits `mysite.com`, I'd like them to be taken to `mysite.com/welcome`. This address is a rewritten version of `mysite.com/index.html` so it's basically appending /welcome onto the address.

I've tried using `Redirect` in my .htaccess however it loops continuously. Is there any way that I could achieve this and still keep the index.html as the welcome page?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^welcome$ /index.html [L]
Redirect 301 / /welcome
```

Comment: Are there all lines in your htaccess?

Comment: @splash58 I've only included the relevant lines - I've removed any redirects that I've tried to create as they haven't worked.

Comment: This lines have no problem. Show all htacces to understand all conversions

Comment: @splash58 I've added my attempt at this; the added redirect gives loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /welcome [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^welcome$ /index.html [L]
```

First line redirects a request made to the root to `/welcome`. Second rule internally rewrites `/welcome` to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing or welcome redirect to /index.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(|welcome)$ /index.html [L]
```